# React Native - task that start on foreground and continue on background

Tags: react-native

React Native.

Is there a way to invoke a task - while app on foreground - and if the user closed the app, the task will continue on background?

IOS & Android support of course.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use native modules for this. Some library can do this for you. But you shouldn't forget, they are just library. they are may not be enough.

[react-native-background-task](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-background-task)

[Native modules for react native](https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-intro)

[Android background threading](https://developer.android.com/guide/background/threading)

Comment: Thanks - please note that react-native-background-task will start only when the app move to the bg. I prefer a task that begins in foreground and once the app is closed will continue on background.

Comment: @chenop Hello there, did you make any headway with your inquiry? I'd like to know myself the answer to your question.

Comment: @ahmet-sahin those are libraries that help to run the task on background - not exactly what I asked for

Comment: @OliverSaintilien didnt find one - AFAIK - you ran the task either on background or foreground - no option to transit a foreground task to background